# Is it ever a good idea to enumerate a python range so you get the index twice?

Tags: python

Sorry for the weird title but I couldn't think of a better way to explain it. I saw someone do this once and didn't think it was a good idea but I wanted to check. Basically, he wanted to return the numbers 0-3 and do two different things with them. Say he wanted to use one as a key to a dictionary and the other in a value calculation, like this:

```
d{0:0, 1:1, 2:4, 3:9}
```

So he did this to return the index twice:

```
d = {}
for i, v in enumerate(range(4)):
    d[i] = v**2
```

Is that better than writing `d[i] = i**2`? I thought it was weird to enumerate `range(4)`. I know this might be somewhat subjective but is this bad design or just a preference thing? What's the best practice?

Comment: No, that doesn't make sense.

Comment: It's not the worst thing I've ever seen.  One thing it does is clearly delineate that there are two things going on; I'd find it very odd to see an index variable also participating in a calculation.  The other thing it does is set up `v` to potentially do something different later, without having to rewrite the whole thing.

Comment: It would probably make more sense if it wasn't `range(4)`, but something like `for i, v in enumerate(range(4, 8))`. But I guess python programmers would prefer a dictionary comprehension, rather then the for loop: `d = {i: v**2 for i, v in enumerate(range(4, 8))}` results in `{0: 16, 1: 25, 2: 36, 3: 49}`

Answer (score 1):

This is not great design. For starters it would be less efficient to enumerate the range.

The code you provided would produce the same result as this:

```
d = {}
for i in range(4):
    d[i] = i ** 2
```

I would recommend trying variations out in the python console. The advantage your code has over this is that it sets up i and v so if you did want to modify either of these in different ways it could make it clear, especially for maths students (I have seen a whole host of unpythonic things which they do)

Comment: or even just `d = {i: i**2 for i in range(4)}`. Using an enumerate() would just obfuscate the intention of the loop